# Promises for going through URLS

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, promise

I'm trying to figure out a way to process through a dynamic number of URLS. The idea is to have a while run until we reach the limit of whatever we are searching for - let's say URLS for example.

```
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        var links = [];
        var uri = feed.uri;
        var promise;
        var loadMore = true;
        var waiting = false;
        var page;
        while(loadMore) {
            if(!waiting) {
                waiting = true;
                promise = getListings(uri, feed, limit);
                promise.then(function(result) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                        if(links.length < limit) {
                            links.push(result[i]);
                        }
                    }
                    if(links.length < limit) {
                        // Load Pagination
                        uri = paginator.process(uri, feed, opts);
                        waiting = false;
                    } else {
                        resolve(links);
                        loadMore = false;
                    }
                }); 
            } 
        }
});
```

This is currently what I've got but it's not running correctly. What I need it to do is go through the original URL and then continute to go through the next page, adding the URLS to the link list. You can assume that paginator works and returns the next URL for that specific website (ex. www.google.com/page2) getListings works fine and returns an array of links.

How would I be able to chain these promises so it can go through any number of pages (if they exist), and return the full array of links that it finds?

I can't seem to be able to change the loadMore variable to false when the limit is reached inside of promise.then(). I would like it to be able to go through the first URL and then the next URL until the limit is reached.

I appreciate any resources or ideas on how to put this together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use recursion with your promise instead of the loop. Something like this:

```
var links = [];
function fetchNext(result) {
    for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        if(links.length < limit) {
              links.push(result[i]);
        }
    }

    if (links.length < limit) {
        // Load Pagination
        uri = paginator.process(uri, feed, opts);

        // Recursion
        return getListings(uri, feed, limit).then(fetchNext);
    }
    else {
         return Q.fulfill(links); // Return resolved promise
    }
}

// Start recursion
var promise = fetchNext([]);
// or var promise = getListings(uri, feed limit).then(fetchNext);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming :

- `getListings()` to be asynchronous
- `paginator.process()` to be synchronous
- a function wrapper named `getLinksAsync`
- a promise implementation with a `catch()` method.

then the whole thing can be performed recursively (without any ugly flags and with error recovery) as follows :

```
function getLinksAsync() {
    function get(links, uri) { //like the outer function, get() returns a promise of links  
        return getListings(uri, feed, limit).then(function(result) {
            if(result && result.length) { //safety, in case getListings() gives a null or empty array
                links = links.concat(result).slice(0, limit);
                if(links.length < limit) {
                    return get(links, paginator.process(uri, feed, opts)); //recurse
                } else {
                    return links; //desired terminal condition - resolve the entire recursion with `links`.
                } 
            } else {
                return links; //resolve the entire recursion with links already discovered
            }
        }).catch(function(err) { //unpredicted error
            console.error(err);
            return links; // recovery - return any links already discovered before the error occurred.
        }); 
    }
    return get([], feed.uri);//seed the recursion with an empty array and feed.uri
}
```

*If the `if(result)` safety is not safe enough, you might consider a try/catch structure*

Usage :

```
getLinksAsync().then(function(links) {
    //`links` array is available for use
    //its length may be anything from zero to `limit`
});
```